# Android studio AVD error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When i started the AVD this errors happens in Run tab so much errors i donot know what is the problem 
My PC ram is 3 gb ram
My Android studio version 2.1.1
I made the AVD's ram 1536
and the VM heap is 384

```
D:\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_22_2

Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Android

Creating filesystem with parameters:
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 POPCNT
    Size: 69206016
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
    Inodes per group: 4224
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
    Inode size: 256
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
    Blocks: 16896
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
    Block groups: 1
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:188 error 0x501
distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:188 error 0x501
TextureDraw: Could not create/link program: .
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/Dell/.AndroidStudio2.1/config/options/usage.statistics.xml"
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
VCPU shutdown request
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
VCPU shutdown request
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=80000001 EBX=01bab000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000
ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fbd000 EBP=00100000 ESP=0050b684
EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000004ff620 00000030
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fb7000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000500
```

can anyone help me please,
Best Regards,
Goodbye.

Comment: Change your AVD Ram to 750 and then check it out whether it's working or not.

Comment: @VinothVino look at the answar because i cannot comment because comment char. limit

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you downloaded Intel HXAM from android SDK as viewed in following pic[image]

and that you downloaded the images system of the android version the emulator has as follows;
[image]

And make sure your PC is Intel in the first place, 
If non of this worked try to test on physical devices or use GenyMotion or BlueStacks third party emulators.

Good Luck